# How to express complexity of two functions considering it is the same in big O notation

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

I have two functions. `a` and `b`.

Both have linear complexity `O(n)`.

```
fcn a (items)
    loop items -> item
        ...
```

```
fcn b (items)
    loop items -> item
        ...

    loop items -> item
        ...

    loop items -> item   
        ...
```

Though `b` obviously takes 3 times longer to run than `a` for the same input.

**Is there any other notion / technical way to express the difference?**

Or is it normal to say "it takes 3 times longer but still O(n) in time so w.e, let's move on"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Big O notation is oblivious to this difference. This is one of its downsides.

One reason we use big O notation in the first place is that the exact running time depends on the system used to run the algorithms. It is meaningless to say that a given algorithm takes X instructions, since X depends on the CPU, the compiler, and so on. However, in some cases we can find a proxy for the running time which is meaningful to look at.

The prototypical example is the number of comparisons in a comparison-based sorting algorithm. In many cases, number of comparisons is a good proxy for the overall running time, and this is a "dimensionless" quantity which is meaningful to compare across algorithms.

Another option is to implement your algorithms as efficiently as possible, and then compare their running time empirically. In a practical paper, this is a very reasonable thing to do.

In your particular case, you can just say that algorithm B invokes algorithm A three times, and consequently is three times slower. This is not reflected in big O notation, but is quite precise and meaningful.

Comment: Additionally, it is not unusual to explicitely mention "constant factors" in or next to a big O-notated complexity. For the algorithms in question "O(n) vs. O(3n)" or "O(n) (with constant factor 1) vs. O(n) (with constant factor 3)" is totally OK, especially if context gives clarity.

Comment: It is quite unusual (and meaningless)  in my field. Perhaps it’s usual in other fields.